# make all parent divs as tall as their own children using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of position absolute parent divs and some child elements in each of them, they are not identical at all but they all have the same class "force-middle"
What I want to do is to calculate the total height of each div's children and apply it to the parent div

what I have so far is this:

```
var total = 0;

$(".force-middle").each(function() {
   $(this).children().each(function() {
        total = total + $(this).outerHeight();
    });
    $(this).css({"height":total});
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI: The class "force-middle" belongs to parent divs

Comment: Do you get any errors in console? Please share more details

Comment: no , no errors the JS works fine but it applies the claculated height of first parent to all other parent div's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize total variable each for a parent like this

```
var total = 0;
$(".force-middle").each(function() {
 total = 0
 $(this).children().each(function() {
    total = total + $(this).outerHeight();
 });
 $(this).css({"height":total});
});
```